# What did Jason mean in Euripides Medea by saying what use do you have of children?

Tags: greek, interpretation

I'm writing an essay on the hubris of Jason in Euripides Medea and while reading it, I still don't understand what he means by this line. So Jason is explaining to Medea that he left her because he wanted to ensure that his children would be rich and live a life like a royal and then he says this:

I wish to raise my children as befits my noble house,

and father brothers for these sons I’ve had by you;

to put them on a par, to unify the line,

and so achieve a happy life

**For you … what need of children do you have?**

Whereas for me it cashes in a gain to benefit

my living sons through those as yet unborn.

Not bad, my long-term planning? (Lines 562-568)

For you … what need of children do you have? This is the line I'm confused about, is he saying that she is only needed to create children and that she isn't useful for anything else?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's more along the lines of Jason needing children to continue his 'noble line', the implied insult being that Medea has no noble line and therefore no need to have children. As Medea is the daughter of a King, this is an insult both to her and her family.

Comment: And of course we know what happens after that.